# One-half shift in argument of Dedekind eta function

Tags: special-functions, modular-forms

There is a known identity
$$ \eta\bigg(z+\frac{1}{2}\bigg) = e^{i\pi/24}\,\frac{\eta(2z)^3}{\eta(z)\,\eta(4z)}\,,$$
where $\eta(z) = q^{1/24}\,\prod_{n\geq 1} (1-q^n)$ is the Dedekind eta function, with $q = e^{2\pi i z}$.

My question is if some simpler connection between $\eta(z+1/2)$ and $\eta(z)$ is known?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean algebraic connection, then no. That is, any algebraic equation between
 $\,\eta(z)\,$ and $\,\eta(z+1/2)\,$ must be homogeneous and therefore the quotient would satisfy an algebraic polynomial equation and hence be constant.
The $\,\eta\,$ function is a modular form and there are many theorems from modular form theory that constrain its properties.

The simplest connection I know is: 
$\, \eta(z)^8 + 16\eta(4z)^8 = (\eta(z+1/2)/e^{i\pi/24})^8. \,$